# What is the two_factor_authentication.recovery_codes_regenerated security event in the GutHub account

Tags: account-security, multi-factor, github

I made some changes to my GitHub account security, notably I added two new hardware security keys and removed SMS as a 2FA backup method.

8 days later today, I randomly checked the GitHub's own [security log](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/reviewing-your-security-log) and found that next to these 3 events, there's also a 4th one from the same day - `two_factor_authentication.recovery_codes_regenerated`. That alarmed me a little. I went to view the codes to potentially re-generate and securely store them again, but the codes were the same as those I stored a few years ago.

On top of that, a new event appeared in the security log, now as expected - `user.two_factor_recovery_codes_viewed`. That surprised me because it now seems like interacting with the recovery codes falls under some sort of `user` type or namespace, instead of the `two_factor_authentication` type.

I tried to look up what the original event could be caused by, but to no success. I'm not too concerned right now - the fact the codes weren't touched (and the fact that regenerating them requires viewing them first) suggest this wasn't a result of someone compromising my account. Still, I'd rest easier knowing why did adding 2 hardware keys and removing an SMS number caused this weird 4th event to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several hours after posting this question, GitHub released a [statement](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-18-false-alert-flags-will-appear-in-users-security-log-due-to-a-bug-in-2fa-recovery-events/) that these messages were caused by a bug during an upgrade to the 2FA platform.

> The storage format of the per-user value GitHub uses to generate your recovery codes was updated, causing the watch job to trigger the erroneous `recovery_code_regenerated` event.

This also explains the discrepancy between one event using the `user` prefix and the other using the `two_factor_authentication` prefix - the accidental event was triggered by an automated watcher, not a user, and thus got assigned a different prefix/owner.